# Repeated pinging of USB scanner best practice - use Handler or Bound Service + Handler?

Tags: android, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I'm in a dilemma, and not sure of the best practice in how to solve it.

I have an app that needs to scan barcodes from a USB scanner, retrieve some data from the web based on the code scanned and show the result to the user.

I've got the scanner-part working through some horrible hacking code now, and need to refactor it into a proper codebase. My dilemma stems from this:

---

**THE QUESTION**

In order to retrieve the latest scanned value from the scanner, I have to ping it for data. The use case requires the scanner to scan non-stop, and not have the user press a button to retrieve the latest data. Therefore, as the UsbConnection API is not event-based, I need to manually ping the scanner for the newest result with a fixed, small interval (about .5 seconds).

---

**SUGGESTIONS**

What's the best way to do this, and why? I have arrived at two possible solutions, but I'm open to other suggestions:

1. Use a Handler in the activity, and fire it's runnable every x milliseconds.

Pro: Fairly simple to implement, follows Android guidelines (AFAIK) on performing work on background thread

Con: Feels dirty to run method in Activity with an interval.

2. Create a bound service to the activity, and in that service, use a Handler to ping the scanner for new data every x milliseconds. If the latest ID scanned is new, report it to the UI.

Pro: Abstract the "dirty" part away from the Activity into a Service

Con: Spawning threads from a thread sounds like a headache to me, but haven't tried it yet. Don't know how java.util.concurrent would handle that?

---

Any tips or suggestions or corrections is much appreciated :-)

Comment: I like the second one more - it's better to be separated from the activity so you can reuse. Spawning a thread is spawning a thread - you have to make sure you kill it when necessary anyway.

Comment: Aren't there some dragons to beware of when spawning threads inside other threads? Or is that just me being pessimistic? :-)

Comment: @jhm There's no problem in spawning threads in threads.